# Hide cursor when entering text

Tags: mouse, gtk, cursor

I use Awesome WM on Fedora 23. When I enter text in Firefox or gVim the mouse cursor stays visible. When entering text in Konsole or Dolphin, the cursor is hidden until I move it again.

The KDE behavior is much more what I want. How can I change this in GTK applications?

Answer (score 5):

There is program called `unclutter` which hides mouse pointer while not in use.
To install it on fedora (if haven't already):

```
dnf install unclutter
```

And then start it with `-idle` option to set number of seconds before pointer will be hidden, e.g.:

```
unclutter -idle 2 &
```

You may want to add above line to `.xinitrc` or similar startup file.

Comment: `unclutter -keystroke` should do (at least partially) what OP is asking for; hide mouse while typing

Comment: @ZN13 That sounds like a system wide option and not something that hinges on the particular toolkit used. I just tested it and it does not work with Firefox for instance. The manual page has a paragraph about this limitation and I fear that this `-keystroke` option does not change the behavior in Firefox. The timeout might be a viable option, though.

Comment: @MartinUeding `unclutter -idle 2` works for me on `firefox` too, just tested. However It is possible that firefox has some built-in option (accessible via `about:config`) to turn such mouse behavior on/off, but I'm not aware of that.

Comment: Sure, the timeout works in every case. Setting this in Firefox seems pointless as that does not help with other programs.

Answer (score 3):

The keystroke option in `unclutter` does not work well. [`xbanish`](https://github.com/jcs/xbanish) does what you demand: no timeout, it hides the cursor when a key is pressed.